# Sort all of a store’s products by an attribute regardless of additional filters

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I thought this would be simple since Magento does provide some nice ways of doing cool little tricks, but what I need to do is simply have all products have a store sort all products that will be listed by a attribute value.  I would not be based in the url params but set so that you programmatically just add the sort on every call for a product collection.  Here is what i have as the first attempt.  in the header.phtml

```
$selected = isset($_GET['gender_orientation'])?$_GET['gender_orientation']:0;

$GenOr=Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('GenOr');
if(!$GenOr||$selected>0){
    Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('GenOr', $selected, null, null, null, null, null);
}
$selected=Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('GenOr');
if($selected>0){
    //Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('gender_orientation', $selected);
    $productcollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $productcollection = $productcollection->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currcategory),true);
    $productcollection = $productcollection->addAttributeToFilter('gender_orientation', $selected);
    //$collection->getSelect()->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
}
```

So the goal is that I read a cookie (atm) and then try to applie the sort before anything is done.  I know in the example I'm returning the collection but there has to be a way to just all pllie to all.  Anyone have ideas..

Jeremy